# Nested Mat-Tree Children Not Displaying in Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, treenode

this is my first time posting a question here in stack overflow and I'm hoping I could get some help with my problem with Mat-Tree as it's not showing the children even though when I console log, the data is there.

I am getting the data from service and I've converted the data so it will be exactly like the model shown in mat-tree documentation example.

```
interface SampleNodeModel {
 id: number;
 name: string;
 type: string;
 children?: SampleNodeModel[];
}
```

Here is my code for getting the data from the service and converting it to the model shown above and assigning it to data source:

```
getData() {
     const dataArray = [];
     const tempModel = {} as SampleNodeModel;
     this.apiService.getSampleData().subscribe(res => {
     tempModel.id = res.id;
     tempModel.name = res.legalName;
     tempModel.type = 'Parent';
    
     const children = [];
    
     res.students.forEach(res2 => {
      const studentList = {} as SampleNodeModel;
      studentList.id = res2.id;
      studentList.name = res2.firstName + res2.lastName;
      studentList.type = 'Student';
      children.push(studentList);
     });
    
     res.teachers.forEach(res3 => {
      const teacherList = {} as SampleNodeModel;
      teacherList .id = res3 .id;
      teacherList .name = res3.firstName + res3.lastName;
      teacherList .type = 'Teacher';
      children.push(teacherList );
     });
    });
    
    tempModel.children = children;
    
    dataArray.push(tempModel);
    
    this.dataSource.data = dataArray;
}
```

And here is the rest of TS file for your reference:

```
treeControl = new NestedTreeControl<SampleNodeModel>(node => node.children);
dataSource = new MatTreeNestedDataSource<SampleNodeModel>();

constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {
 this.getData(); // this is the function above for getting the data
}

hasChild = (_: number, node: SampleNodeModel) => node.children !== undefined && node.children.length > 0;
```

And my HTML code is exactly like what is in the example for Nested Mat-Tree. https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview

Based on the code above, did I do something wrong? When I console.log the dataArray, I'm getting the data with the format just like in the model.. I've been trying to figure out for hours where I went wrong but I can't seem to find it.

When I console.log, here is the format of the data I'm getting:

```
dataArray: 0: {children: Array(29), id: 101, name: 'School Name', type: 'Parent'}
```

All that is displaying is the name of the parent, but the button to toggle and display the children is not there... Hoping someone can help me! Thank you!!!

Comment: Could you please share your code in stackblitz? So that i can debut it.

Comment: @Muthupriya - i have tried to put the project in stackblitz and recreate it but i'm getting an error ''/turbo_modules/@angular/material@10.1.3/index.d.ts' is not a module.".. But I have put on my code in stackblitz and also replicated the data that i'm getting from API in the services. Here is the link: [link]<https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nfadu7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts> Thank you so much for trying to help me!

Comment: I resolved your ''/turbo_modules/@angular/material@10.1.3/index.d.ts' is not a module" issue and able to see your children now.
@hanzoac

Comment: @Muthupriya- thank you for your help. I have actually resolved this issue and will post how it was resolved.

Comment: @Muthupriya - may I know how you resolved the  ''/turbo_modules/@angular/material@10.1.3/index.d.ts' is not a module" issue? Thank you!

Comment: You have wrongly imported the **MatIconModule**. Actually  we have to import icon module from this way. **import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon'**

Answer (score 0):

We were able to finally get the children to show by removing the block of code for calling the API in the getData() function and placing it in ngOnInIt and the getData() function is just used for giving value to the data source is called after the API has finished loading.

I'm not sure about this, but possibly, the reason is that I'm already giving value to the data source when the loading of API is still not finished (if i'm explaining it correctly). Anyway here are the changes that we have made to my code based from the code in the question above.

```
treeControl = new NestedTreeControl<SampleNodeModel>(node => node.children);
dataSource = new MatTreeNestedDataSource<SampleNodeModel>();

dataArray = [];
tempModel = {} as SampleNodeModel;

constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {
}

ngOnInIt(): void {
 this.apiService.getSampleData().subscribe(res => {
     this.tempModel.id = res.id;
     this.tempModel.name = res.legalName;
     this.tempModel.type = 'Parent';
    
     const children = [];
    
     res.students.forEach(res2 => {
      const studentList = {} as SampleNodeModel;
      studentList.id = res2.id;
      studentList.name = res2.firstName + res2.lastName;
      studentList.type = 'Student';
      children.push(studentList);
     });
    
     res.teachers.forEach(res3 => {
      const teacherList = {} as SampleNodeModel;
      teacherList .id = res3 .id;
      teacherList .name = res3.firstName + res3.lastName;
      teacherList .type = 'Teacher';
      children.push(teacherList );
     });
     
    this.getData(); // calling the function after getting the data from the API     

    });

}

hasChild = (_: number, node: SampleNodeModel) => node.children !== undefined && node.children.length > 0;

getData() {
    
    this.tempModel.children = children;
    this.dataArray.push(tempModel);
    this.dataSource.data = null;
    this.dataSource = new MatTreeNestedDataSource<SampleNodeModel>();
    this.dataSource.data = dataArray;
}
```